# Django: url and content creation results in 500 and no apache error log entry

Tags: django

If i try to open a created url i get an 500 error.

My procedure was:

First `python manage.py startapp black`

I added in `project/settings.py` under `INSTALLED_APPS` `'black',`

I added in `project/urls.py` `url(r'^test/', include('black.urls')),`

Content of `black/urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from black import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

And content of black/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("SHOW ME: BLACK")
```

After all i synced the database.

I can't see any error in apache-error-log and also not in my posted django files. What could cause this?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY Yes. My admin site if working correctly.

Comment: Do you have the same problem in development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look a the several handy ways to [log errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) with django.
For production, you will want to configure your logging behavior.
You can find an example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#an-example) in the same docs.

What I personally do in production is enabling email logging, it sends me an email each time there is a fatal error.

Let's see what it would look like for logging both by mail and in a file:

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/your_application.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll have a look.